# I'm unable to add an app to FB to stream my Google+ posts to my FB page. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: facebook, google-plus, facebook-apps

I'd like to have my Google+ feed show up on one of my FB pages.  So I logged into FB, and located the app: [Google Plus Tab for Pages](https://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=266863793334392&pages).

I installed the app (and the tab) and get the message **Your tab is not configured correctly yet.**

Underneath, there's a button, **Configure**.

I click configure and put in the appropriate details, my Google+ numbers, which of my FB pages I'd like to add it to, etc. .... Then select **Change**.

Then I get the following error, no matter what computer I use, what browser I use, etc.:

```
Google+ to Pages

Add Google+ to your page

Don't forget to configure your settings after adding the tab.

Please help us keep the tab ad free.  $5   $10   $20   $50   Any amount  
Developed by    
Privacy Policy
```

The key here is Don't forget to configure your settings after adding the tab -- which I've already done.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Facebook site usage.

Comment: That's why I used the Facebook tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also wish to look at Friends+Me (https://plus.google.com/105750980959577516811/posts) to see if it will work better or suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks Prisoner for your response.  I wasn't aware of Friends+Me, but I tested it out and things look good!  I mainly post on our company's Google+ Page, but I've been looking for something to post on our FB page also -- and I have FB set up to post to our Twitter page, so it covers those three.  Hootsuite just doesn't seem to do what I need it to do.  Thanks again for taking the time to respond!